# Reuse parameter of callback / Reuse channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, architecture, rabbitmq, amqp

I would like to reuse a RabbitMQ channel in different node modules. Since the channel is created asynchronously, I am not sure what the best approach would be to "inject" this channel object to other modules.

If possible, I would like to avoid external dependencies like DI containers for this.

Below, you find my simplified code.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

**web.js**

```
require('./rabbitmq')(function (err, conn) {
    ...

    // Start web server
    var http = require('./http');
    var serverInstance = http.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000, function () {
        var host = serverInstance.address().address;
        var port = serverInstance.address().port;

    });
});
```

**rabbitmq.js**:

```
module.exports = function (done) {
    ...

    amqp.connect(rabbitMQUri, function (err, conn) {
       ...

        conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
            ...
            // I would like to reuse ch in other modules
        });
    });
}
```

**someController.js**

```
module.exports.post = function (req, res) {
   // Reuse/inject "ch" here, so I can send messages
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could always attach your channel handle to `global` object and it can be accessed across module:

```
// rabbitmq.js
    
global.ch = ch
    
// someController.js
    
global.ch // <- is the channel instance
```

I would prefer to inject the handle into each function because i think it is more explicit and easier to reason about and unittest.  You could do that with partial function application

with [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#partialRight):

```
var post = function (req, res, rabbitMQchannel) {
    // Reuse/inject "ch" here, so I can send messages
}
    
var ch = getYourChannel();

// post is function object that accepts two params, and the
// third is bound to your channel

module.exports.post = _.partialRight(post, ch);
```

a third option is to have rabbitmq.js export a function to getting a channel.  A channel could be a singleton so there would only ever be one instance of it.  Then any method that whats a channel handle would request one from the method, which wouldn't require channels to be passed around through functions, or globally.

Comment: Thanks! I definitely like the approach with partialRight. Still, I have one question. How would I implement ```getYourChannel()``` in this case? Could this simply be ```global.ch```?

Comment: I could imagine `rabbitmq.js` exporting a function that returns `conn` so that it could be used from various places.  it could be a singleton, so that only one `conn` would ever be created, even if called multiple times, that reference would always be a single connection.  if it were a singleton you could get a handle to the channel from anywhere using your `getYourChannel()` method and then explicitly passing in channel to your post function wouldn't be necessary!!!

Comment: Thanks, that's how I did it.